# Stop Text Notifications From Showing On Edge

Tags: sms, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I have the Galaxy Note Edge and have tried the stock app, Handcent as well as Chomp, but all of them will display a text message on the Edge Screen.

I have disabled the display message over lock screen option, and no messages are displayed there, but the preview shows on the Edge.

How can I disable that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to see if I could find a filter which would let you choose which notifications you would want to display on the edge and which you would not.  That way you could use the Edge deal, but get rid of the SMS notifications.  In all my searches I can only find a setting on how to disable/enable all or no notifications.

"Edge Screen Settings - Samsung Galaxy Note® Edge

Check out this Edge Screen [video](http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/samsung-galaxy-note-edge-using-edge-screen-video/) for more information.

From a Home screen, navigate: Apps > Settings> Edge screen.

The following options display:

1. Manage panels
2. Express me
3. Information stream
4. Night clock
5. Edge screen text
6. Edge screen timeout
7. **Notifications**

   - Shows notifications on the Edge screen.

     - Enabled when a checkmark is present.
       Use Edge screen on left

Alternatively: you can access the Edge screen settings by swiping upward on the Edge screen from the bottom then tapping Settings icon."

Reference: http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-140340/

Now I do not own an Edge variety of phone myself (I will not buy a phone personally that does not allow me to swap out my battery and/or does not allow me to use an external SD Card).  So there could still be a way I am unaware of to set it so you can use Edge for notifications and then just block those notifications you do not want to display.  Of course this is ONLY notifications you can still have the clock/date and news feed and other stuff still running on the Edge while notifications do not.

Comment: That was it, thank you!  I have had this phone for almost 2 years and I immediately changed the setting when I got the phone, but the recent "upgrade" to marshmallow changed it again.